# Yii2: Different ways of declaring model scenarios?

Tags: validation, yii2, validationrules

I have some questions regarding Yii Scenario
(*this concept is pretty new to me*)

If I have `Post` class which extends `Model`
and have the following attributes

```
public $id;
public $title;
public $body;

CONST SCENARIO_SAVE = 'save';
CONST SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';
```

is

```
// Code 1
public function rules() {
    return [
            ['id', 'integer'],
            [['title', 'body'], 'string'],
            [['id', 'title', 'body'], 'required']
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_SAVE => ['id', 'title', 'body'],
        self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['title', 'body']
    ];
}
```

the same as

```
// Code 2
return [
        ['id', 'integer'],
        [['title', 'body'], 'string'],
        [['id', 'title', 'body'], 'required', 'on' => 'save'],
        [['title', 'body'], 'required', 'on' => 'update']
];
```

is code 1 and 2 the same thing?

will the `'id', 'title', ‘body’`safe from mass assigned for both codes or should i specify ’safe’ rules for code 1?

Answer (score 1):

**Code 1** and **code 2** are not the same.
**You will need to specify all safe attributes for each scenario**

```
> `// Code 1
public function rules() {
    return [
            ['id', 'integer'],
            [['title', 'body'], 'string'],
            [['id', 'title', 'body'], 'required']
    ];
}`
```

For **code 1** All the three attributes `id, title, body` will be required during both create and update actions.

```
> `// Code 2
return [
        ['id', 'integer'],
        [['title', 'body'], 'string'],
        [['id', 'title', 'body'], 'required', 'on' => 'save'],
        [['title', 'body'], 'required', 'on' => 'update']
];`
```

For **code 2** `id, title, body` will be required if you set the model scenario to `save` using `$model->scenario='save';`

When `$model->scenario='update'`, `title` and `body` will be required.

Here is an example of how we set the scenario of a model.Assuming the `Post` class.

```
public function actionMyAction(){
    $model = new Post;
    $model->scenario = 'save';//changing the scenario which you want to use

    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())){
       // the rest of your code here....

        if($model->save(true,$this->scenario)){
          //return true if all the attributes passed the validation rules
        } 
    }
}
```

Here are some few other links that can help you get started with Scenarios

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#scenarios%28%29-detail
http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-scenarios/

Comment: you sure about that? look at my code 1 again, i put the scenario method there